# parcel: a JSON parsing library in C

Tags: performance, c, parsing, json, library

[I've created a JSON parsing library in C](https://github.com/syb0rg/parcel), and would like some feedback on it (feel free to submit a pull request on GitHub).  Any and all suggestions are acceptable, but I would prefer if reviews were focused on making this more efficient.

My header file:

```
#ifndef _json_H_
#define _json_H_

/**
 * JSON type identifier. Basic types are:
 *  o Object
 *  o Array
 *  o String
 *  o Other primitive: number, boolean (true/false) or null
 */
typedef enum { JSON_PRIMITIVE, JSON_OBJECT, JSON_ARRAY, JSON_STRING } JsonType;

typedef enum
{
    JSON_ERROR_NOMEM = -1, // Not enough tokens were provided
    JSON_ERROR_INVAL = -2, // Invalid character inside JSON string
    JSON_ERROR_PART = -3, // The string is not a full JSON packet, more bytes expected
    JSON_SUCCESS = 0 // Everthing is fine
} JsonError;

/**
 * JSON token description.
 * @param       type    type (object, array, string etc.)
 * @param       start   start position in JSON data string
 * @param       end     end position in JSON data string
 */
typedef struct
{
    JsonType type;
    int start;
    int end;
    int size;
    #ifdef json_PARENT_LINKS
    int parent;
    #endif
} JsonToken;

/**
 * JSON parser. Contains an array of token blocks available. Also stores
 * the string being parsed now and current position in that string
 */
typedef struct
{
    unsigned int pos; /* offset in the JSON string */
    unsigned int toknext; /* next token to allocate */
    int toksuper; /* superior token node, e.g parent object or array */
} JsonParser;

/**
 * Create JSON parser over an array of tokens
 */
void json_initJsonParser(JsonParser *parser);

/**
 * Run JSON parser. It parses a JSON data string into and array of tokens, each describing
 * a single JSON object.
 */
JsonError json_parseJson(JsonParser *parser, const char *js, JsonToken *tokens, unsigned int tokenNum);

#endif /* _json_H_ */
```

My C source code:

```
/** 
 * @file json.c
 * @brief JSON Parser
 */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include "json.h"

/**
 * @fn static JsonToken *json_allocJsonToken(JsonParser *parser, JsonToken *tokens, size_t tokenNum)
 * @brief Allocates a fresh unused token from the token pull.
 * @param parser
 * @param tokens
 * @param tokenNum
 */
static JsonToken *json_allocJsonToken(JsonParser *parser, JsonToken *tokens, size_t tokenNum)
{
    if (parser->toknext >= tokenNum) return NULL;
    JsonToken *tok = &tokens[parser->toknext++];
    tok->start = tok->end = -1;
    tok->size = 0;
    #ifdef json_PARENT_LINKS
    tok->parent = -1;
    #endif
    return tok;
}

/**
 * @fn static void json_fillToken(JsonToken *token, JsonType type, int start, int end)
 * @brief Fills token type and boundaries.
 * @param token
 * @param type
 * @param start
 * @param end
 */
static void json_fillToken(JsonToken *token, JsonType type, int start, int end)
{
    token->type = type;
    token->start = start;
    token->end = end;
    token->size = 0;
}

/**
 * @fn static JsonError json_parsePrimitive(JsonParser *parser, const char *js, JsonToken *tokens, size_t num_tokens)
 * @brief Fills next available token with JSON primitive.
 * @param parser
 * @param js
 * @param tokens
 * @param num_tokens
 */
static JsonError json_parsePrimitive(JsonParser *parser, const char *js, JsonToken *tokens, size_t num_tokens)
{
    JsonToken *token;
    int start;

    start = parser->pos;

    for (; js[parser->pos] != '\0'; parser->pos++)
    {
        switch (js[parser->pos]) 
        {
            #ifndef json_STRICT
            /* In strict mode primitive must be followed by "," or "}" or "]" */
            case ':':
            #endif
            case '\t': 
            case '\r': 
            case '\n': 
            case ' ':
            case ',': 
            case ']': 
            case '}':
                goto found;
        }
        if (js[parser->pos] < 32 || js[parser->pos] >= 127)
        {
            parser->pos = start;
            return JSON_ERROR_INVAL;
        }
    }
    #ifdef json_STRICT
    /* In strict mode primitive must be followed by a comma/object/array */
    parser->pos = start;
    return JSON_ERROR_PART;
    #endif

    found:
    token = json_allocJsonToken(parser, tokens, num_tokens);
    if (!token)
    {
        parser->pos = start;
        return JSON_ERROR_NOMEM;
    }
    json_fillToken(token, JSON_PRIMITIVE, start, parser->pos);
    #ifdef json_PARENT_LINKS
    token->parent = parser->toksuper;
    #endif
    parser->pos--;
    return JSON_SUCCESS;
}

/**
 * @fn static JsonError json_parseString(JsonParser *parser, const char *js, JsonToken *tokens, size_t num_tokens)
 * @brief Fills next token with JSON string.
 * @param parser
 * @param js 
 * @param tokens
 * @param num_tokens
 */
static JsonError json_parseString(JsonParser *parser, const char *js, JsonToken *tokens, size_t num_tokens)
{
    JsonToken *token;
    int start = parser->pos;

    parser->pos++;

    /* Skip starting quote */
    for (; js[parser->pos] != '\0'; parser->pos++)
    {
        char c = js[parser->pos];

        /* Quote: end of string */
        if (c == '\"')
        {
            token = json_allocJsonToken(parser, tokens, num_tokens);
            if (!token)
            {
                parser->pos = start;
                return JSON_ERROR_NOMEM;
            }
            json_fillToken(token, JSON_STRING, start+1, parser->pos);
            #ifdef json_PARENT_LINKS
            token->parent = parser->toksuper;
            #endif
            return JSON_SUCCESS;
        }

        /* Backslash: Quoted symbol expected */
        if (c == '\\')
        {
            parser->pos++;
            switch (js[parser->pos])
            {
                /* Allowed escaped symbols */
                case '\"': 
                case '/': 
                case '\\': 
                case 'b':
                case 'f': 
                case 'r': 
                case 'n': 
                case 't':
                    break;
                /* Allows escaped symbol \uXXXX */
                case 'u':
                    /// \todo handle JSON unescaped symbol \\uXXXX
                    break;
                /* Unexpected symbol */
                default:
                    parser->pos = start;
                    return JSON_ERROR_INVAL;
            }
        }
    }
    parser->pos = start;
    return JSON_ERROR_PART;
}

/**
 * @fn JsonError json_parseJson(JsonParser *parser, const char *js, JsonToken *tokens, unsigned int num_tokens) 
 * @brief Parse JSON string and fill tokens.
 * @param parser
 * @param js
 * @param tokens
 * @param num_tokens
 */
JsonError json_parseJson(JsonParser *parser, const char *js, JsonToken *tokens, unsigned int num_tokens) 
{
    JsonError r;
    int i;
    JsonToken *token;

    for (; js[parser->pos] != '\0'; parser->pos++)
    {
        char c;
        JsonType type;

        c = js[parser->pos];
        switch (c)
        {
            case '{':
            case '[':
                token = json_allocJsonToken(parser, tokens, num_tokens);
                if (!token) return JSON_ERROR_NOMEM;
                if (parser->toksuper != -1)
                {
                    tokens[parser->toksuper].size++;
                    #ifdef json_PARENT_LINKS
                    token->parent = parser->toksuper;
                    #endif
                }
                token->type = (c == '{' ? JSON_OBJECT : JSON_ARRAY);
                token->start = parser->pos;
                parser->toksuper = parser->toknext - 1;
                break;
            case '}':
            case ']':
                type = (c == '}' ? JSON_OBJECT : JSON_ARRAY);
                #ifdef json_PARENT_LINKS
                if (parser->toknext < 1) return JSON_ERROR_INVAL;
                token = &tokens[parser->toknext - 1];
                for (;;)
                {
                    if (token->start != -1 && token->end == -1)
                    {
                        if (token->type != type) return JSON_ERROR_INVAL;
                        token->end = parser->pos + 1;
                        parser->toksuper = token->parent;
                        break;
                    }
                    if (token->parent == -1) break;
                    token = &tokens[token->parent];
                }
                #else
                for (i = parser->toknext - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    token = &tokens[i];
                    if (token->start != -1 && token->end == -1)
                    {
                        if (token->type != type) return JSON_ERROR_INVAL;
                        parser->toksuper = -1;
                        token->end = parser->pos + 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                /* Error if unmatched closing bracket */
                if (i == -1) return JSON_ERROR_INVAL;
                for (; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    token = &tokens[i];
                    if (token->start != -1 && token->end == -1)
                    {
                        parser->toksuper = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                #endif
                break;
            case '\"':
                r = json_parseString(parser, js, tokens, num_tokens);
                if (r < 0) return r;
                if (parser->toksuper != -1) tokens[parser->toksuper].size++;
                break;
            case '\t':
            case '\r':
            case '\n':
            case ':':
            case ',':
            case ' ': 
                break;
            #ifdef json_STRICT
            /* In strict mode primitives are: numbers and booleans */
            case '-':
            case '0':
            case '1':
            case '2':
            case '3':
            case '4':
            case '5':
            case '6':
            case '7':
            case '8':
            case '9':
            case 't':
            case 'f':
            case 'n':
            #else
            /* In non-strict mode every unquoted value is a primitive */
            default:
            #endif
                r = json_parsePrimitive(parser, js, tokens, num_tokens);
                if (r < 0) return r;
                if (parser->toksuper != -1) tokens[parser->toksuper].size++;
                break;

            #ifdef json_STRICT
            /* Unexpected char in strict mode */
            default:
                return JSON_ERROR_INVAL;
            #endif

        }
    }

    for (i = parser->toknext - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        /* Unmatched opened object or array */
        if (tokens[i].start != -1 && tokens[i].end == -1) return JSON_ERROR_PART;
    }

    return JSON_SUCCESS;
}

/**
 * @fn void json_initJsonParser(JsonParser *parser)
 * @brief Creates a new parser based over a given buffer with an array of tokens available.
 * @param parser
 */
void json_initJsonParser(JsonParser *parser)
{
    parser->pos = 0;
    parser->toknext = 0;
    parser->toksuper = -1;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### What you did well

1. As far as I can tell, the code produces correct output when given correct input.
2. The functions feel like a coherent library, with consistent function names and logical order of parameters.
3. You use a caller-owns-everything memory management policy, which works well for C.

#### What you could improve on

1. The name `json_initJsonParser()` is a bit redundant.  `json_initParser()` should suffice.
2. I don't think that `#ifdef json_PARENT_LINKS` is a good idea.  A user could easily compile the library without support for parent links, yet compile the application with `json_PARENT_LINKS` defined, leading to nasty bugs.  Why not always enable support parent links?  It would be pretty difficult to make sense of the parser output without it.
3. I think that `#ifdef json_STRICT` would be better as a runtime option rather than a compile-time option.  If the user wants to have both modes available, there's no reasonable way to do so.
4. JSON primitives may be numbers, `true`, `false`, or `null`.  You accept illegal primitives such as `truthy`.
5. `json_allocJsonToken()` doesn't "allocate" memory in the sense that I expect.  Also, two of the three calls to `json_allocJsonToken()` are followed by `json_fillToken()`, so you might as well combine the two functions.  Filling in dummy values first is senseless.
6. In the `JsonParser` structure, `toknext` and `toksuper` should be the same data type.  It's weird that one is unsigned and the other is signed.  I recommend just using `int` for both, or possibly [`ssize_t`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19224655/1157100).
7. It is not obvious that the way to extract the results is to use a loop like

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < parser.toknext; i++) {
       //              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   }
   ```

   Please feel free to add some generous comments with usage examples in the header file.

Comment: I don't think using `ssize_t` is a good idea since that would tie the library to POSIX. It's range isn't intuitive either: the only negative value it has to be able to hold  is -1 (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19224809/2073469) in the question you linked).

Answer (score 11):

I think the code looks pretty tidy. Not sure if you can get a huge speed up - you are effectively tokenizing a string by storing the meta data of the tokens (start/end positions and type). This alleviates the pain of having to copy the data and dealing with the associated memory allocation issue.

A few remarks:

1. You could consider changing the token to store a `const char * start` and a `size_t length` instead where `start` points to the first char of the token in the input. This way you can work on the data of the token without having to also pass around a reference to the original string.
2. You have documentation for your methods but you don't really document the parameters - what they are for, what their invariants are etc.
3. For general use the interface is probably too inconvenient - you pretty much need to know how many tokens to expect before parsing (or do the old `parse - fail - double memory - try again` dance) which could be hard to keep track of. As a user I might know what kind of object I want to parse but I'd be hard pressed to know exactly up front how many json tokens I'd need.
4. `goto` is generally frowned upon. While you use it in a fairly straight forward way that's easy to follow I'm almost certain that rewriting the code with a `gotValidToken` token flag to terminate the loop instead could potentially increase readability. The `goto` forces you to jump around while reading the code.